# Class Not Found Exception in WebLogic, Fine in TomCat

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, weblogic

I am using two servers one is tomcat and other one is WebLogic.
I developed two application, one is Main-Application and second is commons-application. 
I added quartz JAR into the commons-application and export it as a JAR and add it in the Main-Application.
For importing quartz JAR into the commons-application I made a lib folder and give the path of it in build path configuration.
Now when I run Main-Application it gives me error that class not found that is associated with quartz.
So I add quartz JAR into the Main-Application too, and run again so it executed fine. 
But when I run same configuration in WebLogic it gave me same error(class no found).
 What am I missing? Do I need to do something else for WebLogic?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about main method apps, but in web apps we have to provide a preference to our classpath jars.
Weblogic being an app server provides its own jars and other services.
And by default it prefers to use its own jars. So if you want to use your own jars which are in your project's class path then you specifically have to mention so.
Tomcat being a servlet container doesn't have its own jars, so it will by default refer to your libraries.
See the prefer web inf classes.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

Similar classpath settings should be available for main class apps, I guess.

Also, more importantly, jars should not be embedded into other jars. (I think you are embedding quarts inside other common jar. Main application should have two jars: commonsapp.jar and quartz.jar in its classpath.)